# How to *append* a text to a database file opened with shelve?

Tags: python

After we create a database file using shelve.open and then close the program, if we run the code again, but with different input(s), it actually *replaces* the text instead of *appending* it.

How may I change this behavior?
For example:

```
    db = shelve.open('store')
    db['some variable'] = some value
    db['another variable'] = another value
    db.close()
```

And now when we write the same code but with different values for the same variable, we *replace* the previous value instead of *appending* the values to it. How can I change that?

Comment: Like [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html)? See 11.4.2 Example

Comment: `db['some variable'] = db['some variable'] + some value` assuming you open the shelve with `writeback=True`.

Comment: What is `some value`? Same question for `another value`. Are they lists? Integers? Texts?

Comment: @martineau I tried that I got an exception, here's the code by the way (remove the test function, it's redundant.):

http://pastie.org/8279816#49-50

Comment: @MakeCents Got the same exception.

Comment: "I got an exception" -- what kind of exception? Also you need to `open.shelve('store', writeback=True)` as I mentioned. Note that you may have a problem the first time because there's no existing `db['some variable']` value -- so you'll have to check for that case and just store `some value` rather than append it.

Comment: @AkshatTripathi, Your test def assigning db is backwards. Should be `db = shelve.open('store')` not `db = open.shelve('store')`. Is that your error? Are you trying to reload the db in the object and then add things and then write it again?

Comment: @MakeCents That 'open.shelve' was actually my mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming* your values are lists:

- Use `db = shelve.open('store',writeback=True)` and then append the value to the same key.
- Since your code does not open `'store'` with `writeback=True` you
  must assign a variable the value of the key, `temp = db['some variable']`, which would be
  `some value`, and then append that variable, `temp.append(another
  value)`, and then reassign that keys value, `db['some variable'] =
  temp`.

Should not your third line of code be `db['some variable'] = another value'` in order to *replace* the value?

**Edit:** Other possible meaning of question?

Do you mean you want to load the database into your object and continue to use your "UI" code to edit it after closing the program? If so then you can do something like:

```
class Update_MyStore(MyStore):
    def __init__(self, store):
        db = shelve.open(store)
        for i in db:
            setattr(self, i, db[i])
        self.items()
        self.store_in_db()
Update_MyStore('store')
```

**Edit:** Another option to update, if that is the case, if you want to add or update specific items:

```
while True:
    store = shelve.open('store',writeback = True)
    Item = input('Enter an item: ').capitalize() #I prefer str(raw_input('Question '))
    if not Item or Item == 'Break':
        break
    store['item_quantity'][Item] = int(input(('Enter the number of {0} available in the store: ').format(Item)))
    store['item_rate'][Item] = float(input(('Enter the rate of {0}: ').format(Item)))
    store.sync()
    store.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your latter solution since that seemed like something of my reach (I am a beginner) and it worked!
Also, if possible, could you explain to me what's happening with, store.sync() and the writeback? 
I actually tried searching for it but I am not able to get a good clarification, so.

Again, thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. It is explained in 11.4 and in 11.4.2 notes in the following link: [Link to sync and writeback Explanation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html)